# access token in android Salesforce sdk

Tags: java, android, salesforce, android-sdk-tools

I am using this url

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=""&client_secret=""&username=""&password=""
```

to get an access token. Can I use that access token in the SDK so that there will be no need to login? I want to develop the application in which I want to use my salesforce credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make use of the access token to login in to the application, but the access token that you have obtained is the short lived one and you have to make use of refresh token to get the new access token once your previous becomes invalid

**Reference**

> https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&language=en